# Populating a PDF with Java Form

Tags: java, pdf, report

Ive searched through similar answers but not quite getting a complete answer so need to explain here.

What i have is a JFrame form that an Employee in a manufacturing plant needs to fill in everytime something goes wrong with the production process.

What i want is for a user to click a "Print Report" JButton on the JFrame form and it will populate the following PDF Report with the info from the JFrame.

JFrame form

[image]

PDF Report

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasperReports is also a good alternative. I've been using it for a while now and it works perfectly for generating/exporting dynamic reports. You only need to design the template once using iReports and you can use it to generate any PDF on the fly.

Comment: Do you think its easier than iText? How difficult or long would it take to replicate this form i need to replicate?

Comment: I haven't used iText before, so might not be able to judge which is easier. iReports has a drag n drop design interface to build the form. Replicating the form should not take up to an hour

Answer (score 1):

I use this library http://itextpdf.com/, you will spend some time programing the form, but then all will be really fast.

Comment: When you say programming the form are you saying its not possible to just write to an existing form rather it has to be made from new?

Comment: In itextPDF  you can program the structure of an empty form, then you can handle it like an objecy setting all the fields like parameters, lately you can export like pdf.

Comment: Sounds ideal. Did you follow some tutorials or did you just teach yourself?

Comment: I followed tutorials directly from the site http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php. Also in youtube you can find information

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Jasper Studio. It does the job perfectly. Has a bit of a learning curve but works 100%.

You can just send the report an SQL Query rather than all the parameters to create a dynamic Report.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio/releases